# How do i know if there is timer activated with AlarmManager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm using the alarm manager to periodically activate a service:

```
Intent i=new Intent(DataCollectionActivity.this, HUJIDataCollectionService.class);
pi = PendingIntent.getService(DataCollectionActivity.this, 0, i, 0);
mgr.cancel(pi);

mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() , 1* 60* 1000, pi);
```

My question is, after I close my application (and the activity of course) and open it again, I need to know if the timer is running, and I need to know how can I stop the timer (I dont have a reference to the time anymore)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The timer has an ID you need to use that, you can cancel the timer with the ID and probably find it as well. Ussually you would just overwrite it with a new timer if that is what you need.

Comment: ok, but i need to know how can i find my timer after getting back to the activity...

Answer (score -1):

From what I've read, it seems that there are no methods to query for alarms, at all. Also, look at [AlarmManager timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635010/alarmmanager-timer) .