# AlarmManager timer

Tags: android

When  useing AlarmManager ,i set many timers,each timer for different broadcast receiver,
 and they will auto merge or not?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(TimeModeService.this,TimeModeReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction("startTimeMode");
    PendingIntent startIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),1000, intent,0);
    can.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, startHour);
    can.set(Calendar.MINUTE,startMin);
    alarmmanager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, can.getTimeInMillis(), (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), startIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In,
`PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),1000 /*this is requestCode*/, intent,0);`

If you keep the requestCode same for different instances of PendingIntent, and then set alarm using them, they should merge, in android 2.3.3, if i keep it same (for starting an activity) only one activity started. Here i would mention that `alarmManager.set` was used not `alarmManager.setRepeating`.

I used int `requestCode = (int)Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()`; to keep the request code different for different pendingIntents.

But [Official Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29) mentions it as

```
requestCode     Private request code for the sender (currently not used).
```

So the best way is to try it for your situation, but different PendingIntents with same requestCode would merge.

Comment: Thank you ,it's useful to me ! 谢谢.